# Please help with prependTo & replace javascript code!

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, replace, prepend

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#divID').each(function() {
        var $select = $('<select id="dropdown" onchange="location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;" />');
        $(this).find('a').each(function() {
            var $option = $('<option />');
            $option.attr('value', $(this).attr('href')).html($(this).html());
            $select.append($option);
        });
        $(this).replaceWith($select);
    });
    $('<option selected="selected" value="#">Select Option</option>').prependTo('#dropdown');
});
</script>
```

Everything works great EXCEPT the prepended option selected="selected" doesn't work in IE.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$('<option value="#">Select Option</option>').attr('selected', 'selected').prependTo('#dropdown');
```

Comment: +1, though I would probably switch places for adding attr and prepending - purely for better readability of the workflow: you add an option first and then you select it

Comment: It worked when I reversed the order ().prependTo.attr Thanks!